# std::stringstream using preallocated stack buffer for writing

Tags: c++

I have a boost::asio::streambuf which I need to fill with the following data:

- The size of the data that follows in bytes
- Data consisting of either string data, or about 50K records of binary data of size 6-8

Currently, I create a `std::stringstream` and use 50K times `write` to fill it with data. How can I use `std::stringstream` and pre-allocate memory, if possible even use the stack? My application is performance sensitive and I want to avoid unnecessary reallocations.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: 300Kb is a lot for stack allocation. You probably don't need to do that. I would begin by just writing the code, then profiling it and see what takes time and if there are allocations or data copying you'll need to eliminate.